# how to check if a bitmape is clicked

Tags: bitmap, libgdx

I have 40 strings ; want to draw them ; and want to get touched font (string) in console (I have searched too much and did not find any sol.)

Comment: Are you using labels to display text?

Comment: There is no bitmap or bitmape in libGDX. Do you mean BitmapFont?

Comment: Soory, it is bitmapfont, okay now what I do is:-added bitmapfont as actor and set bond (using glyphlayout.width and height) but how to check which one is touch (I have 20 bitmapfont )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libgdx, at its base, uses immediate mode rendering, which means (roughly) that when it draws something, it instantly forgets everything about it. So when you use a BitmapFont to draw a text, Libgdx will not keep track of where it is - and will not know itself whether it is clicked by user. In the retained mode, you need to keep track of things you draw for yourself (for example by keeping an `Array` of `Rectangle` objects representing each text you output).

There is an additional API in Libgdx called the Stage API, which uses the retained mode - instead of executing draw operations you can build a scene out of objects representing texts, bitmaps etc. Stage API offers methods to inform you when a screen object is clicked.

Comment: I have 40 strings ; want to draw them ; and want to get touched font (string) in console (I have searched too much and did not find any sol.)

Comment: Have you looked into any documentation for the stage api? Or do you just wait for me to write the code for you?